# How to check if a String contains a substring in any order?

Tags: java, string, substring

This is not same as "How to check if a string contains s specific substring?" . I found a no of questions like that here but not precisely what i am looking for.
I am creating a program at a competitive coding site the problem of which states that we are given a string made of x,y,z and we have to count the number of substrings which contains atleast one of those chars but not all of them.I tried this...

```
    String text = sc.next();
      int l = text.length();
      int count=0;
     for(int j =1;j<=l;j++)
      {
     for(int i1 =0;i1<j;i1++){
        String g = text.substring(i1,j);
        if(g.contains("xyz")||g.contains("xzy")||g.contains("yzx")||g.contains("yxz")||g.contains("zxy")||g.contains("zyx"))
        ;
        else
        count++;




      }

      }
      System.out.println(count);
```

And this worked(atleast for 2 test cases). But for the larger test cases my program is violating the time limit. Now i think that is because of the number of matching conditions in the if clause. I would like to know if there is any way by which i can just check if the substring contains 'xyz' in any order instead of checking for every order.Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

P.S- If anything else is responsible for the time limit violation, do mention out !

Comment: The timing problem comes from the fact that you're using a quadratic solutions, with two nested for loops. This type of solution has a O (n^2) time, while a better one is needed.

Comment: Please post some input strings with awaited results

Comment: The input strings come from input files in which all the cases are tested ! I can't post them right now as i dn hav access to my laptop right now. I will provide that later. As for now, can you provide an alternate to nested for loop ? @lamsomeone &

Comment: Actually, this solution is probably O(n^3) since the `contains` method is probably an O(n) linear search.

Comment: You are splitting this input into very small pieces (text.substring(i1,j);). Why don't you try your contains method on the full text, that will save you a lot of iterations.

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for CodeGolf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought it was a simple regexp? pattern `[xyz]+` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.  Warning untested code!

```
String target = ...

String text = sc.next();
if (target.length() == 0) {
    // matched!
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i <= text.length() - target.length(); i++) {
        if ((pos = target.indexOf(text.charAt(i))) >= 0) {
            boolean[] found = new boolean[target.length()];
            found[pos] = true;
            int matchCount = 1;
     outer: for (j = 1; j < target.length(); j++) {
                pos = 0;
                while (true) {
                    pos = target.indexOf(text.charAt(i + j), pos);
                    if (pos == -1) {
                       break outer;
                    } else if (!found[pos]) {
                       found[pos] = true;
                       matchCount++;
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (matchCount == target.length()) {
                // matched!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to make this faster, one possibility is to clear and recycle the `found` array that we are using "mark off" the characters as we match them.

There may be more significant optimizations.  However, I don't think that the Boyer-Moore "trick" of skipping a number of characters is going to work here.

**UPDATE**

Your original solution is `O(N factorial(M))` where `N` is the text length, and `M` is the target string length.

My solution is `O(N M)`.

The optimal solution involves calculating a running hash by multiplying prime numbers, as described in one of the answers to [How to find all permutations of a given word in a given text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727118/how-to-find-all-permutations-of-a-given-word-in-a-given-text).  I think it is `O(N)` on average.

(Hint: the solution I'm referring to as written looks like it is `O(M N)`.  However, we should be able to use the inverse multiplication equality:

> ((ab mod n) . (b<sup>-1</sup> mod n)) mod n = a mod n

where `a` and `b` are the prime factors and `n` is 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> depending on whether we use `int` or `long`.  Reference: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

This will allow is to "multiply in" and then "inverse multiply out" the characters and therefore update the running hash in `O(1)` operations.)

Comment: Sorry but Optimal solution is what i am looking for !  Your solution too contains a nested for. So that too would probably violate the time limit !

Comment: @KirtyBhushan - You cannot get an *optimal* solution without 2 for loops here. One loop for going through the entire string and another to check for permutations of substring. It is as simple as that

Comment: @KirtyBhushan - Feel free to optimize it then :-)

Comment: I get it ! I too tried to get an answer without the nested loop but didn't succeed !  But then, i too can just go thru the solutions posted by others ! I am trying to do whatever on my own ! Anyways , thanks for the help. I will try to find an optimal sol.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan - One option that can be tried is *backtracking / recursion*. Or reduce your input size using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf()` . But worst case, well. nothing can be done

Comment: @TheLostMind - I don't think recursion or backtracking will help ...

Comment: @StephenC - It could help in *generating* permutations which could then be compared or  used with `indexOf()`

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate question, and the linked question contains a solution that is `O(N)` on average.  Clever.  Read it.

Comment: @TheLostMind - However generating the permutations is `O(factorial(M))` in time and space, and you still have `O(N M)` work to do to look for a match (assuming you use a `HashSet<String>`)

Comment: @StephenC - agreed. It could be improved upon slightly by using caching and *backtracking* (although many stack frames could actually slow down the process. ).. If we have some idea about the *pattern* of input, then a better algorithm / tweak can be proposed.