# Check if a string contains particular characters in any order

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The best way that I can explain what I'm trying to do is by giving an example:

I have a string `StackOverflow` in my database and when a user types `OAW` I would like to return that string and any other word that contains those three characters in any order.

I've tried playing with various LINQ/Lambda expressions but to no avail.

```
query.Where(a => a.SerialNumber.Contains(a));
```

I found a post [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10727118/2658820) that looks similar to mine but it's in Java.

I feel what I'm trying to do is extremely simple to implement but I'm just missing it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
query.Where(str => value.All(str.SerialNumber.Contains));
```

Here for any word in your database, you check if all the characters of the  `value`, `OAW`, -Using the `All` extension method- are contained in the `str.SerialNumber`.

**Update**

This

```
str.SerialNumber.Contains
```

is equivalent to this lambda expression:

```
x => str.SerialNumber.Contains(x)
```

The `x` refers to the random element of the sequence in which we apply the `All`. In other words to the random character of `value`.

Comment: So wasteful to call `ToCharArray`. A string is already `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can do LINQ on it right away. This then turns into Nathan's solution.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen you are completely correct. Thanks for you comment !

Comment: @Christos Where are you getting 'a' from so you can do a.All() ?

Comment: @Christos I was able to get your previous answer working. But i can't seem to figure out how to implement your edited answer. If you can maybe explain how to use your new answer a bit better i will accept this as my answer.

Comment: @HiTech Hi, I had to correct my answer. Let me explain you what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ContainsAll type of function.

```
public static bool ContainsAllItems(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    return !b.Except(a).Any();
}
```

**NOTE**

The function was borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520642/does-net-have-a-way-to-check-if-list-a-contains-all-items-in-list-b)

Comment: Use `IEnumerable<>`, not `List<>`. A string is an `IEnumerable<char>` but not a `List<>`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this method. Still a bit new =/

Comment: So you could write `query.Where(a => !searchLetterStr.Except(a.SerialNumber).Any())`, right? Just to inline and get rid of the method.

Comment: "The function was borrowed from here" - Did you return it yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by just modifying your code a little bit:

```
public bool DoesContain(char[] identifiers, string containingString)
{
    return !identifiers.Except(containingString.ToCharArray()).Any();
}
```

or:

```
private char[] identifiers = { /* Your identifiers*/ };

public bool DoesContain(string containingString)
{
    return !identifiers.Except(containingString.ToCharArray()).Any();
}
```

Either of these methods will return true if the string passed contains any of the specified characters.

**Note:**

Solution from Cameron MacFarland on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332973/check-whether-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another).

Comment: I just tried this. It returns true to any string that contains one of the characters in the char array.

Comment: Did you want it to see if the string contained all characters?

Comment: Yes. I would like it to return true if the "containingString" has at the minimum all the "identifies". I'll edit my post to make that more clear.

Comment: Updated answer to accompany that. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can make multiple comparisons and && them, or use regular expressions. I prefer the former, here's a terse example:

`arrOfCharacters.All(a.SerialNumber.Contains)`

although you may need to litter your code with `ToUpperInvariant()`